# Meaning of notwithstanding in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What is the meaning of "notwithstanding" in the following sentence:

> Most of our platitudes notwithstanding, self-deception remains the most difficult deception.

The quote is taken from the essay "[On Self-Respect](http://www.vogue.com/3241115/joan-didion-self-respect-essay-1961/)" by Joan Didion.

The dictionary definition of the word is: in spite of. However, I do not see how that makes sense here:

> Most of our platitudes in spite of, self-deception remains the most difficult deception.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to make more sense once you get the sentence structure right - even though "notwithstanding" is synonymous with "in spite of", the two phrases differ a little grammar-wise.

> In spite of most of our platitudes, self-deception remains the most difficult deception.

In other words - no matter what kind of clichéd truths one tells themselves, it's not easy to force yourself to believe something that isn't true.

Comment: Does notwithstanding always go at the end?

Comment: Notwithstanding something...  or   Something notwithstanding....  Both are possible.